# Communication between PHP on server and Windows Service on clients

Tags: c#, php, wcf, windows-services, client-server

I have a PHP script on linux server that writes some data into database when some events occurs and now I want this script sends this data to my windows clients. There will be windows services on clients that catch data sent from server and do some stuff.
I have done something like this before but with WCF and C# programming on both server and client sides.
Now, I don't know how to do this with php on server side and c# on client side.

Comment: You're expected to make some effort yourself before asking a question here. My suggestion is to try to figure out how the communication is happening using WCF and see if there's something that uses the same technology for PHP (SOAP is I think an important keyword to google here).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had some progress using SOAP. Now I can create a webservice in PHP and call it from winform with the help of this article: http://www.sanity-free.org/125/php_webservices_and_csharp_dotnet_soap_clients.html. The issue is in this article winform client request server by clicking the button and get the response while I want php script notifies winform client of events whenever something happens in server side.